# Cannot assign value of type 'Void' (aka '()') to type '() -> Void'

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, void, type-mismatch

There is a class instance of `UIView` that acts like a button. 
It has the property:

```
public var endPressAction:(()->Void)?
```

There is also a controller with the method:

```
func didPressCell(_ indexPath: IndexPath){
```

I'm trying to pass the controller's method as a parameter to the "button" like this:

```
button.endPressAction = self.didPressCell(indexPath)
```

But I get the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Void' (aka '()') to type '() -> Void'

Does anybody know the method of conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of conversion:

```
button.endPressAction = { self.didPressCell(indexPath) }
```

Comment: By the way, this code introduces a strong reference cycle. You should use `[weak self]` or `unowned self]` pattern within this closure.